# ViEmu & Resharper: How to "Redo"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, viemu

I'm trying out ViEmu with Visual Studio 2010 & R#. In Vim I use ctrl-r to redo, but in ViEmu and VS ctrl-r doesn't work. The status bar says "Waiting for second key of chord". I assume this is for shortcuts like R# Rename (Ctrl-r,r)

Is there some way to enable ctrl-r as redo for viemu while still keeping the (Ctrl-r, *) shortcuts for resharper?

Comment: Workaround: use Ctrl+Shift+Z.

Comment: I tried that in insert and normal mode and it did not appear to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to just type ":red[o]" (the 'o' is optional) in normal mode.  Otherwise you can fix the Ctrl-R mapping.  I believe you can customize mappings in some vimrc type file Viemu uses and then just map :red to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have though so, it sounds like they would conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I do a key sequence Alt -> E -> R which results in calling Redo from Edit menu.
Far from being perfect but works.

This may not be a real key key chord but still much better than grabbing a mouse.

Comment: Well, the emacs keychords aren't much enhanced than that, and they work alright.